# html5 localstorage not working the way I want

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML5's localstorage to save two variables and load them when the user refreshes the page but something doesn't work properly when loading the saved item:

var's:

```
var cookies = 0;
var cursors = 0;
```

saving code:

```
window.setInterval(function(){

    var save = [cookies, cursors];
    localStorage["save"] = JSON.stringify(save);
    console.log("Saved game");

}, 1000);
```

loading code:

```
function load() { 
    var state = JSON.parse(localStorage["save"]); 
    console.log("Loaded game");
}
```

What my console show's on page load:
[13,1]
Loaded game
[0,0]
Saved game
[0,0]
Saved game
[0,0]
Saved game
Etc.

The `load()` function gets called on body load `(<body onload="load()">`
and I DO get the console message "Loaded game"...

Comment: `[cookies, cursors]`? What are `cookies` and `cursors`?

Comment: Have you checked, that the items get correctly serialized?

Comment: Yea, please check the output of `JSON.stringify(save)`. I can't see a problem with your current code.

Comment: You didn't say what goes wrong. Do you get anything at all in "state". If you test on Chrome you can pop up the developer tools (Ctrl-Shift-I) go to the resources tab and choose localStorage in the left hand pane. Then you should see what's been stored.

Comment: So, what doesn't work?

Comment: When I load the page, the load function works properly, and gets the saved data, but then something overwrites it on the first interval

Comment: Try sessionStorage instead of localStorage

Comment: So, I see where you are loading the state but I don't see where you are assigning the loaded state to `cookies` and `cursors`.

Comment: At some point you overwrite `cookies` and `cursors` with the content of `state`, right?

Comment: When I use sessionStorage everything does the same, but still it overwrites the saved item on the first interval (saving the game again)

Comment: yep @Sirko, at the very top of my js file: var cookies = 0; var cursors = 0;

Comment: And where you update them? What is the point of using `localStorage`, when you do not use your variables, that got loaded.

Comment: sorry but I don't exactly understand what you're trying to explain me @Sirko

Comment: Made a little edit to my code (added the 2 var's)

Comment: I would suggest you to expose your whole code, because these little snippets aren't being very illustrative.

Comment: In your function load, you have to overwrite `cursors` and `cookies`, else in the next iteration of you `setInterval()` the values in `localStorage` will be overwritten by your default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You syntax seems fine. However, JSLint recommends using dot notation on localStorage:

```
localStorage.save = JSON.stringify(save);
```

and

```
var state = JSON.parse(localStorage.save);
```

Then you can just add your state variable to the `console.log` statement to check it:

```
console.log("Loaded game: "+state);
```

Remember, your values have been saved as an array, so you'll have to access them with `state[0]` and `state[1]` to get the individual values.

Comment: The problem with using the dot notation is that you can't work with dynamically generated keys. I, personally, prefer to use the `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your localStorage access. Also, you don't need to try sessionStorage if is localStorage what you are looking for.

The problem, I think, is with how are you dealing with your data.

Judging by your code, you are reading the localStorage data and storing it into a local variable called `state` and doing nothing more with it.

Fact: if you are REALLY getting to save your data to localStorage with the

`localStorage["save"] = JSON.stringify(save);`

then the

`var state = JSON.parse(localStorage["save"]);`

would actually work, if performed anytime after the previous snippet. So, if your application is actually getting to run the snippet where you save the data, then later when you run the `load` function, the local variable `state` will have the content `[0, 0]`.